# How to subset data table, group, and compute on j, in R

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, subset

I am trying to modify the column `newCol` from the data table `dt` only for the smallest `year` within group `g1` and `g2`.

Here is a minimal example. As you can see, I succeeded to do what I want, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant or 'datatablish' way to do it. I only want answer in the data.table format if possible!

```r
library(data.table)
# Dummy data
dt = data.table(year = c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2001, 2005, 2000, 2008),
    g1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), g2 = c(88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 54, 54))

# Set up new col to foo
dt[, newCol := "foo"]

# Correct the value for the minimal year, by group g1 and g2
dt[dt[, .I[which.min(year)], by = .(g1, g2)][, V1], newCol := "bar"]
```

Comment: Are you OK with a solution using the `dplyr` package, or only the `data.table` package?

Comment: Sorry, I should have be more explicit: I prefer to stay in the data.table world. (Edited the question)

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do this in a single line with

```
dt[,   newCol := c("foo", "bar")[1 + (year == min(year))], .(g1, g2)]
```

Comment: Many thanks, but it does not exactly do what I want. With your solution the line 4 remains 'foo' instead of becoming 'bar'

Comment: @mistral I didn't notice it, it may be a bug.  Added another option

Comment: Quite elegant, many thanks! I cannot vote for your answer (not enough reputation), but I buy it!